# how to add angular material design carousel?

Tags: angularjs

I am using code for carousel shared on following link:

http://codepen.io/Fabiano/pen/LACzk

HTML Code:-

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
<div>
  <carousel interval="myInterval">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
      </div>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

CSS Code :-

```
 #slides_control > div{
    height: 200px;
    }
img{
  margin:auto;
  width: 400px;
}
#slides_control {
  position:absolute;
  width: 400px;
  left:50%;
  top:20px;
 margin-left:-200px;
}
```

JS Code:-

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
  $scope.myInterval = 3000;
  $scope.slides = [
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
    }
  ];
}
```

If I implement above code then it don't work even my existing ui.bootstrap module don't work properly.

Comment: do you check your console, is there any error?

Comment: I had try to put this in my solution but after adding  ['ui.bootstrap']  my project is display blank output.

Comment: then verify that you're including this `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>` after `angular.min.js`